# debugging very slow in Xcode 4.5 and 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

First, sorry for my poor English.

Problem appears on my ipod touch 4 which is iOS 5.1.1. When I add breakpoints, it takes Xcode long time to run. But it's OK if there's no breakpoint and it's also OK on iphone which is iOS 6.0(added breakpoints).

The first time I launch device debug, I saw an error 'Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC002)' in Organizer-Devices, and I found solution by stackoverflow(Adding three dyld armv7 files, and all of them are zero-byte files. I don't know if they caused this problem.)

Environment: macbook air OSX 10.8.3, Xcode 4.5/4.6.

Comment: ipod touch is jailbreak and iphone is not.

Comment: Using a jailbroken device for debugging is not a good idea.  Expecting proper performance on such a device is not really rational.  If you are testing apps which are to be distributed, it also represents a very non-standard operating environment which will be unlike that of your users.

Comment: You are right. But is works fine until I update Xcode from 4.3 to 4.6.

Comment: I tested other devices. First, an iphone with iOS 5.1.1(jailbreak), it has the same problem and Xcode doesn't stop at the breakpoint, just jump into the assemble code. Then, an iphone with iOS 4.3.3(jailbreak), surprisingly, it works fine.

Comment: in directory '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport', there are variant iOS versions like '4.3.3', '5.1.1', '6.0.1'. Each directory has similar sub directories, but I found that 5.1.1 is a bit different. Under Sub directory 'Symbols/System/Library', 5.1.1 just has one dir 'Caches', but other versions have more directories like 'Frameworks', 'CoreServices' and so on. And under sub dir 'Caches/com.apple.dyld/', the file 'dyld_shared_cache_armv7' is of size 144M, and the file under '5.1.1' is 0 byte.

Comment: I have mentioned error 'Xcode has encountered an unexpected error (0xC002)' in my question, which is solved by adding that file manually, could anyone tell me why that file is not generated automatically.

Comment: Finally, I uninstall the whole Xcode, remove all files by sudo 'find / -name 'Xcode'. Now it works fine on iOS 5.0.1, but still failed on that ipod touch 5.1.1. I don't want to go ahead any longer because i have spent 2 days on it, which makes me almost mad. I think this is just an accident. I remembered I used a tool to upgrade the ipod to 5.1.1 because at that point only 6.1 is allowed by apple, maybe it's the answer. Thanks very much for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to update to Xcode 4.6.2? I was having this issue, but it was fixed on 4.6.2.